# Qt Views [not] updating upon underlying structure of the model changes

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller

I have encountered an issue that is most likely WAD but I still need to solve. I originally thought it was a problem with my custom models but it is in fact present with Qt native model classes as well.

Consider this little program: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9MLVHQaeHKxeFBSYzVGVF9sQ0U/edit?usp=sharing

It is just fresh Qt GUI app with 2 `QTreeViews` and two sets of buttons for inserting/removing rows and columns on each view. The underlying models are `QStandardItemModel` in one view and `QIdentityProxyModel` in the other. The navigation is accomplished by clicking on the models – the index is stored and then used by the buttons.

Try inserting/removing rows and columns and you will notice that the views do not update right after the underlying data structure will have changed. Rather they will be updated after you hover over them. And that is the problem because in my other project I have incoming network data that updates the model data that is being displayed to user via standard Qt views. Therefore I need the views to be updated after the data changed and NOT when user hovers over them which he may not do as he may not be aware of the change.

You may notice there is the `updateViews()` function where I have tried to force-update the views. Neither `update()` nor `repaint()` changed anything. The former probably correctly as the documentation says but the repaint should as I understand it cause the widgets to get repainted… Is there any other way to force-update the views?

Also, the reason why I set up the proxy model is that in my project the proxies are heavily used and therefore I need to cause the view-update via them rather than via external slot/function call as is the case in the example given. But if need be this could work as a work-around as well.

Thanks!

EDIT: Problem is manifesting with **columns** manipulation only it seems. See detail in comments below.

Comment: I don't see your problem. Adding  model.setData(modelIndex.sibling(modelIndex.row()+1, modelIndex.column()), QVariant(111)); in insert row function and pressig "insert row" correctly updates both models in qt 5.1. Even with updateViews commented out

Comment: @Zeks The rows are usually updated correctly although there is some fishy behaviour for last rows. The most problematic are columns in my experience, both adding and removing.

Comment: yeah, you are right, definitely something fishy with columns

Comment: @Zeks Yeah. :-) Upon further investigation of QTreeView class I have noticed that there are slots only for rowsAboutToBeRemoved/Inserted and rowsRemoved/Inserted which explains why rows are ok. There are then protected slots for column count change but it apparently does not cause the content to be redrawn as well. And it would explain why the header actually move upon insert/remove of columns but contents update only when hovered over.

Comment: Some links for anyone who would want to track this issue:
My Qt bug report: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-39261
Related Qt bug report: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-31028
Qt Forums topic: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/43057/